# How to add custom view xib file dynamically

Tags: swift, xcode, uiview, xib

I am beginner. Thank you for help. I want to add a custom view to scrollview. I have to set label text but can't do because it's nil.
I tried this way.

```
var y = 50;
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: 350, height: 200);
for i in 0...10
{
    let view = MyView2();
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
    view.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: y, width: 300, height: 100);
    y = y + 150;
    view.lblName.text = "Test : \(i)";
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: 350, height: y);
    self.scrollView.addSubview(view); 
}
```

This is my customView. I added xib file and I am sure I choose xib file custom class.

```
class MyView2: UIView {
    @IBOutlet weak var lblName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var myButton: UIButton! 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialise the view like that-

```
 let view = UINib(nibName: "nib file name", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
```